# How to Use aframe eventsystem with two targets

Tags: aframe

I want to trigger one Event with one click, or two events at one click at aframe.

I've using the included eventsystem by aframe, but if i give one Objekt two events, one will be ignored. The same if i give one event to targets.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.3/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a-scene>
 
   <a-plane color="#CCC" height="200" width="200" position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
    
   <a-box ID="BlueToRed" position="-1 1 -4"></a-box>
   <a-box ID="RedToBlue" position="1 1 -4"></a-box>
   
   <a-box position="-1 0 -1" 
   event-set__down="_event: mousedown; _target: #BlueToRed; color: red"
   event-set__down="_event: mousedown; _target: #RedToBlue; color: blue"
   > </a-box>
   
   <a-box position="1 0 -1" 
   event-set__down="_event: mousedown; _target: #RedToBlue; color: blue; _target: #BlueToRed; color: red"> </a-box>
   
 
    
    
  <a-camera>
        <a-cursor></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>
    
    
   
  </a-scene>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't define two targets, but you can attach two `event_set` components if they have different names:

```
event-set__downBtR="_event: mousedown; _target: #BlueToRed; color: red"
event-set__downRtB="_event: mousedown; _target: #RedToBlue; color: blue"
```

Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ow4rz15t/) fiddle.

Comment: If you don't have further questions feel free to mark the answer :)